# AWS SES - Receiving email to s3 not working

Tags: amazon-ses

I have configured AWS SES for receiving emails to AWS S3 bucket. Followed Below Steps :-

1. Create Verified identities i.e. a@domain.com (using Email address so didn't setup any MX records).
2. Send a test mail from a@domain.com to another verified email address b@domain.com. It is working.
3. Setup Rule set to create rule :-

   ```
   Status is Enabled
   Spam and virus scanning is Enabled
   Recipient condition - a@domain.com
   Action - Deliver to Amazon S3 bucket (bucket created using SES so, policy is correct)
   ```
4. Got the file AMAZON_SES_SETUP_NOTIFICATION into the S3 bucket but whenever I receive any new mail to a@domain.com is not found in s3.
5. Rule set is also in active state.

Can anyone please help me why i am not receiving mail into s3.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in your setup. It is impossible for AWS SES to receive any information for the mail that you have, without specifying the MX records. Those records would point to the mail servers of Amazon, so that whenever an email is sent, it is received by them and they can process it.

The verified email addresses concept is used mostly for the sending. By approving the email address, you verify that you can use this email address to send on the behalf of it - not to receive the emails.

What is more, receiving an email works only on the domain level. So you cannot specify in the MX records the specific email addresses. The way to overcome this, is to use some subdomains for instance:
@a.domain.com to go to SES and normal emails will go to your normal email provider.

One last thing - the receipt rules in the amazon SES allow you for configuring the receiving emails on the specific address to give you the possibility to create the special address, such as no-reply/general/etc. Mostly you would prefer to have all of your emails routed in the similar way/routed based on the subdomain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76399638/failing-to-receive-emails-in-s3-bucket-using-ses

could you help me with this issue?