# Failing to receive emails in S3 bucket using SES

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am trying to create a system where emails will be sent to my company's mail, and an S3 bucket will store those emails. Whenever a new email is stored, a Lambda function will be triggered to store the email and reply back to the sender (2nd part).
However, I have been unsuccessful in implementing the first part.

I have a domain hosted on AWS Route 53, dummy.io.
I have created an MX record: 10 inbound-stmp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. Then, I verified the domain on SES. Since the domain was already hosted on Route 53, I didn't need to do any extra work to complete the verification.
After that, I created a rule set and inside that, I created a Receipt rule. I didn't add anything in the Recipient conditions. I added an S3 bucket action and created an S3 bucket. The object key prefix is contact@dummy.io.
The policy is as follows:

```
jsonCopy code{    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSESPuts-id",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ses.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::email-temp-test/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:Referer": "account id"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When the S3 bucket was created, a new folder was created under that (contact@dummy.io), and under that folder, the AMAZON_SES_SETUP_NOTIFICATION file was created.
I then sent a couple of emails to contact@dummy.io from abc@gmail.com, and the emails were sent successfully. However, no file/object was created in the S3 bucket. I fail to understand why.
Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Do you use KMS adidtionally or no? Please check those docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-permissions.html